# Why does putting a socket in a queue close it?

Tags: python, multithreading, sockets, socketserver

I'm writing a server that operates with a fixed number of workers, each with different properties (in the snippet below, `n` is such a property.

Upon getting a request, I would like to put it into a queue, so the first available worker can deal with the task.

Unfortunately, the socket gets closed when it's enqueued.

```
import threading
from queue import Queue
import socketserver

thread = True

queue = Queue()


class BasicHandler(socketserver.BaseRequestHandler):
    def handle(self):
        while True:
            sock = self.request
            byte = sock.recv(10)
            print(byte)

class ThreadedHandler(socketserver.BaseRequestHandler):
    def handle(self):
        queue.put(self.request)

def worker(n):
    print('Started worker ' + str(n))
    while True:
        sock = queue.get()
        byte = sock.recv(10)
        print(byte)

if thread:
    [threading.Thread(target=worker, args=(n,)).start() for n in range(2)]
    handler = ThreadedHandler
else:
    handler = BasicHandler

socketserver.TCPServer.allow_reuse_address = True
server = socketserver.TCPServer(("localhost", 9999), handler)
server.serve_forever()
```

Running the above snippet with `thread = False` works as fine, but when I try to connect to the `thread = True` version, telnet immediately says:

```
Connection closed by foreign host.
```

and the server prints:

```
Started worker 0                                                                                                                               
Started worker 1                                                                                                                               
b''
```

Comment: You should not misuse LC as for-loops.

Comment: @Daniel: can you go into a bit more detail on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The request is automatically closed, when the method `ThreadedHandler.handler` finished. You have to override `TCPServer.shutdown_request` if you want to keep the socket open.